# Changing the value of an Additional Event Field in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, event-calendar, tribe-event-tickets

I am using Events Calendar Pro in Wordpress and have set up an Additional Field which I would like to change the value of in my functions.php code. The field is a dropdown with 2 options that I would like to switch between on each event based on a condition.

So far I've used `update_post_meta($post_id, '_ecp_custom_2', 'Available');` however this doesn't seem to do anything. When manually setting the field value then var dumping the result of `get_post_meta($post_id, '_ecp_custom_2', true)` it shows the correct value so _ecp_custom_2 must be right?